# Magento Override Community Controller from a local module

Tags: magento, controller, local, overriding

I would like to override a "community" controller from a local module". I found a lot of tutorials about overriding a core controller but nothing about a community controller.

Magento version : 1.6.1

My current state is :
- override a core controller => OK
- override a community controller => KO

Here's my file tree :

```
- community
  - Namespace
    - Mycommunitymodule
      - controllers
        - IndexController.php
- local
  - Namespace
    - Mylocalmodule
      - controllers
        - Mycommunitymodule
          - IndexController.php
      - etc
        - config.xml
```

source of my local module

```
<mycommunitymodule>
   <args>
    <modules>
     <Namespace_Mylocalmodule  before="Namespace_Mycommunitymodule">Namespace_Mylocalmodule_Mycommunitymodule</Namespace_Mylocalmodule>
    </modules>
   </args>
</mycommunitymodule>
```

source code of my overrided controller :

```
<?
$origDir = Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Namespace_Mycommunitymodule').DS;
require_once $origDir.'IndexController.php';
class Namespace_Mylocalmodule_Mycommunitymodule_IndexController extends     Namespace_Mycommunitymodule_IndexController
{
 public function indexAction() {
      zend_Debug::Dump("test surchargé");
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks almost correct.
Try replacing

```
<Namespace_Mylocalmodule  before="Namespace_Mycommunitymodule">Namespace_Mylocalmodule_Mycommunitymodule</Namespace_Mylocalmodule>
```

by

```
<Namespace_Mylocalmodule  before="Namespace_Mycommunitymodule">Namespace_Mylocalmodule</Namespace_Mylocalmodule>
```

and the class name **Namespace_Mylocalmodule_Mycommunitymodule_IndexController**  by **Namespace_Mylocalmodule_IndexController** as of its filename and folder if needed.